# Having an hard time fetching data from sql query using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script and connects to a database, then inserts data into a database. However I am having an issue fetching the data.

Here is the error message I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\forms\db.php on line 24

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the script

```
<?php
    //This script provides connection to the database//
    //Connect
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    try {
        $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thetest', $user, $pass);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
    }

    //Insert
    try {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `users`(`name`, `lastname`, `age`) VALUES(?,?,?)");
        $stmt->execute(array("Dave", "Smithers", "22"));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

    //Fetch
    try {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `lastname` = 'Smithers'");
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $user = $result->fetchAll();
        print_r($user);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$stmt->execute()` returns a boolean indicating success/failure.

Instead, use this:

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Should have been a comment

Comment: Really I can't detect difference in your code with the code question .. What is that ?

Comment: @stack - The user believed $stmt->execute() returned a result set when it returns a boolean